# Is it right to say "I've compensated that day that I didn't work"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What is the correct way to say that I've worked to cover some hours that I didn't work on a specific day of the week? Let's say that I work 8 hours every day, but on Monday I worked only 4, but on Friday I _______ the hours that I didn't work on Monday.

Can I use the verb cover or compensate?

Comment: *Made up for, caught up on, worked overtime*. If you want to use *compensate* it has to be *compensate for*. "Compensate the hours" means that the hours got money from you. This is a question better suited for our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage) (for which you need 20 reputation points) or for [our sister site for learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (for which you need none).

Comment: Whether or not you can use those verbs depends on the exact meaning of what you're trying to convey. Both *cover* and *compensate* might work—however, they mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb **to make up for** is a good fit. [Longman defines it in this sense as:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-up-for)

> [to] replace something that has been lost; [synonym] compensate